# How to drop rows that contain NaN from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like this. How do I get rid of the rows that contain a Nan?

I have tried several iterations, for example

```
df = df.dropna()
```

none of them work

```
     pSpot        quoteDatetime underlyingSymbol           expiration  strike optionType     bid     ask  underlyingBid  underlyingAsk      iv       id
0   1.0000  2017-01-06T12:00:00              SPX  2017-01-20T00:00:00    2280          C 13.0000 14.0000      2277.4000      2278.0800  9.3101   0.0000
27  1.0000  2017-01-06T12:00:00              SPX  2017-02-17T00:00:00    2280          C 26.7000 27.9000      2277.4000      2278.0800  8.9137  27.0000
113 1.0000  2017-01-06T12:00:00              SPX  2017-03-17T00:00:00    2280          C 39.3000 40.7000      2277.4000      2278.0800  9.5947 113.0000
253 1.0000  2017-01-06T12:00:00              SPX  2017-04-21T00:00:00    2280          C 52.5000 54.1000      2277.4000      2278.0800 10.0710 253.0000
0   1.0010  2017-01-06T12:00:00              SPX  2017-06-16T00:00:00    2280          C     NaN     NaN      2277.4000      2278.0800 10.5000      nan
0   1.0010  2017-01-06T12:00:00              SPX  2017-09-15T00:00:00    2280          C     NaN     NaN      2277.4000      2278.0800 11.1300      nan
0   1.0010  2017-01-06T12:00:00              SPX  2017-12-15T00:00:00    2280          C     NaN     NaN      2277.4000      2278.0800 11.5800      nan
0   1.0010  2017-01-06T12:00:00              SPX  2018-01-19T00:00:00    2280          C     NaN     NaN      2277.4000      2278.0800 11.7200      nan
0   1.0010  2017-01-06T12:00:00              SPX  2018-06-15T00:00:00    2280          C     NaN     NaN      2277.4000      2278.0800 12.1000      nan
0   1.0010  2017-01-06T12:00:00              SPX  2018-12-21T00:00:00    2280          C     NaN     NaN      2277.4000      2278.0800 11.7600      nan
0   1.0010  2017-01-06T12:00:00              SPX  2019-12-20T00:00:00    2280          C     NaN     NaN      2277.4000      2278.0800 12.0600      nan


df.head.to_dict() is not very enlightening:

{'pSpot': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.01, 3: 1.01, 4: 1.01}, 'quoteDatetime': {0: '2017-01-06T12:00:00', 1: '2017-01-06T12:00:00', 2: '2017-01-06T12:00:00', 3: '2017-01-06T12:00:00', 4: '2017-01-06T12:00:00'}, 'underlyingSymbol': {0: 'SPX', 1: 'SPX', 2: 'SPX', 3: 'SPX', 4: 'SPX'}, 'expiration': {0: '2017-01-20T00:00:00', 1: '2017-01-20T00:00:00', 2: '2017-01-20T00:00:00', 3: '2017-01-20T00:00:00', 4: '2017-01-20T00:00:00'}, 'strike': {0: 2280, 1: 2285, 2: 2290, 3: 2295, 4: 2300}, 'optionType': {0: 'C', 1: 'C', 2: 'C', 3: 'C', 4: 'C'}, 'bid': {0: 13.0, 1: 10.4, 2: 8.7, 3: 6.5, 4: 5.1}, 'ask': {0: 14.0, 1: 11.4, 2: 9.2, 3: 7.4, 4: 5.9}, 'underlyingBid': {0: 2277.4, 1: 2277.4, 2: 2277.4, 3: 2277.4, 4: 2277.4}, 'underlyingAsk': {0: 2278.08, 1: 2278.08, 2: 2278.08, 3: 2278.08, 4: 2278.08}, 'iv': {0: 9.3101, 1: 9.088, 2: 9.1241, 3: 8.9417, 4: 8.902}, 'id': {0: 0.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 3.0, 4: 4.0}}

print(df.dtypes)

pSpot               float64
quoteDatetime        object
underlyingSymbol     object
expiration           object
strike                int64
optionType           object
bid                  object
ask                  object
underlyingBid       float64
underlyingAsk       float64
iv                  float64
id                  float64
dtype: object
```

This is really frustrating. if I try to convert the `bid` column to a string, it doesn't work:

Before:

```
print(df.dtypes)

pSpot               float64
quoteDatetime        object
underlyingSymbol     object
expiration           object
strike                int64
optionType           object
bid                  object
ask                  object
underlyingBid       float64
underlyingAsk       float64
iv                  float64
id                  float64
dtype: object
```

After

```
df[['bid']] = df[['bid']].astype(str)
print(df.dtypes)

pSpot               float64
quoteDatetime        object
underlyingSymbol     object
expiration           object
strike                int64
optionType           object
bid                  object
ask                  object
underlyingBid       float64
underlyingAsk       float64
iv                  float64
id                  float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: have you tried this - df.dropna() ?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: yep, doesn't work

Comment: You have `NaN` and `nan` in your frame it may be that one of those is a string 'nan' and not `np.nan`. Can you run `df.head().to_dict()` so we can see what the _exact_ type of data you're working with. Also `dropna(how='all')` would only drop rows that are all NaN of which you have none in your sample set. So what would the expected output be for the provided frame?

Comment: I added the output of to_dict in the post

Comment: @Ivan `bid` column is already string type (object type). So, nothing is changed from `df[['bid']] = df[['bid']].astype(str)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# Drop rows which have any NaN (you need to use this)
df2=df.dropna()
```

[image]

```
# Drop rows which have all NaN in its row
df2=df.dropna(how='all')
```

[image]

```
# Drow rows which have at least 2 NaNs
df2=df.dropna(thresh=2)
```

[image]

```
# Drow rows which have NaNs in specific column
df2=df.dropna(subset=[1])
```

[image]

---

Note.

To expect the result as you predict, data type of columns should be consistent

Following code might work only if 3 columns data type are consistent, for example, float in following example

```
df2=df.dropna()
```

So, before using above function, check the data type of your dataframe by using `print(df.dtypes)`

[image]

Comment: Doesnt't work. The last one looked promising. The right syntax is df.dropna(subset=['bid'])

Comment: @Ivan Did you get the processed dataframe with new variable like df2, for example, `df2=df.dropna()`? Or you can use inplace option like `df.dropna(inplace=True)` and your `df` is the processed one.

Comment: @Ivan And the data type in columns looks strange. In `id` column, it's `nan` and in `other columns` they show `NaN`. Check the data type of each column by using `print(df.dtypes)`

Comment: See original post. Modified to show dtypes

Comment: @Ivan As far as I know, the the data type should be consistent to apply `df.dropna` to delete `any NaN` in `all columns`. So, try to change data type of `id` column to string `df[['id']]=df[['id']].astype(str)` and use `df.dropna()`

Comment: @Ivan To make all columns data type consistent, you can convert all column data type to string by using `df[['pSpot','quoteDatetime','underlyingSymbol','expiration','strike','optionType','bid','ask','underlyingBid','underlyingAsk','iv','id']]=df[['pSpot','quoteDatetime','underlyingSymbol','expiration','strike','optionType','bid','ask','underlyingBid','underlyingAsk','iv','id']].astype(str)`

Comment: This is really bizarre. Sometimes the columns are NaN, sometimes they are nan. I am calling SqlServer for these values. I might have a subtle bug in that code

Comment: @Ivan Pandas dataframe automatically detects data type and automatically set data type to optimal data type when loading data from like CSV file. If you loaded data from SqlServer using pandas, check the data type in SqlServer

Comment: Nice info `@YoungMinPark`

Answer (score 0):

Two things;

1: the 'how' parameter specifies how many items in the row / column need to be NaN in order for it to be dropped. So by setting `how='all'`, it will only drop the rows which are all NaN. If you want to drop rows that contain NaN in any space, you can specify `how='any'`, which is the default.

2: As others have said, calling the operation without passing `inplace=True` will not modify the dataframe. You have can either assign the operation to a dataframe, or pass the `inplace=True` agrument. I believe best practice is to assign to another df as the inplace argument will be deprecated and has larger overhead than returning the value.

Try this:

```
df2 = df.dropna()
```

Or:

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: I am assigning the return value back to the original

Answer (score -2):

You are effectively dropping the `NaN` rows. However, the method returns a new copy with the rows removed. You need to do this:

```py
df=df.dropna()
```

Or use `inplace=True`, which will alter the original dataframe.

```py
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: I am assining the value to the dataframe. I left that out for brevity